# What does "Après, vous vous êtes embrassés?" mean?

Tags: traduction

Does this question simply mean:

1-"After that, you kissed each other?"

Or does it have a more complex meaning depending on the context like:

2-"After you kissed each other [you went to the Eiffel tower]?"

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

The meaning is the first one:

> And then, did you kiss each other?

Your second meaning would have required the conjunction *que* instead of a comma:

> Après que vous vous êtes embrassés, vous êtes allés à la tour Eiffel ?

or no comma and an infinitive:

> Après vous être embrassés, vous êtes...